# Best way to mimic inheritance in postgresql?

Tags: orm

For an application I am writing, there are two types of "users", those who have made accounts and those who have not, `virtual_users`. These two types are nearly identical, except `account_users` have a `password`, and `email` is required and must be unique amongst all `account_users`, although it can be the same as any number for `virtual_users`. A large number of tables have a column that references `users`, which should include both, and 90% of app functionality treats them as interchangeable. What is the best way of handling this? Some options I have considered:

-Put both types of users in the same table and have a complicated constraints regarding uniqueness, basically, if `password` is not NULL, `email` must be unique among all `users` where `password` is not NULL. I have no idea how I would write this constraint. On the few occasions I only want `account_users` query for only `users` who have a `password`. This seems like the best solution if I can figure out how to write the constraint.

-Have `Account_users` inherit from `Virtual_users`and `Virtual_users` has an additional column `password` and unique constraints on `email`. From here there are two potential options:

---Have a `Users` table which includes two columns `account_user_id` and `virtual_user_id` one of which is NULL and one of which corresponds to the appropriate user. When other tables need to reference a `user`, they reference this table. Have all my queries server side for users query both tables and combine.

---When other tables need to reference they reference either table. I don't think this is possible. Have all my queries server side for users query both tables and combine.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the scenario is you have a system which some parts require the user to be signed into a registered account, and others do not, but you'd still like to track users.

[Postgres has table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-inherit.html). You could use that, but I'd be concerned about the caveats.

You could put them all into one table and use some sort of flag, like [Single Table Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance), but then you run into constraint issues. You would then enforce constraints in the model. This should be fine if you have a strong model.

You could have separate `accounts` and `users`. Rather than one being a special case of the other, they key is thinking of them as two conceptually different things. In OO terms, an account [has a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) user.

```
-- Visitors to the site who haven't signed up.
create table users (
    id          serial,

    -- The unverified email they might have given you.
    email       text,

    -- Any other common information like a tracking token
    token       text
);

-- Users who have registered.
create table accounts (
    id          serial,
    user_id     int references users(id),

    -- Their verified email.
    email       text not null,
    -- Hashed, of course.
    password    text not null

    -- any additional information only for accounts
);
```

I like this because there are no flags involved, `users` and `accounts` can have separate constraints, and the `accounts` table doesn't get bloated with users that showed up once and never came back.

You'd access complete account information with a simple join.

```
select accounts.*, users.token
from accounts
join users on accounts.user_id = users.id
where accounts.id = ?
```

If you want to delete an account you can do so without losing the underlying user information.

```
delete from accounts where accounts.id = ?
```

Systems which require an account use accounts. Systems which don't use users. Systems which behave differently for users and accounts can check if a user has an account easily.

```
select accounts.id
from accounts
where accounts.user_id = ?
```

User tracking is associated with the `users` table, so you have a consistent record of a user's behavior before and after they register.

Comment: Thank you! This is an incredibly helpful and comprehensive answer. So much better than anything I was considering and it will save me a ton of headache down the line.